# Using modulo to map multiple list items to a slot (round robin) but also maintain overall order when popping no matter how many items are added

Tags: python

I have two lists of tasks.

```
items = list(range(1, 20))
items2 = list(range(1, 20))
```

I want to round robin allocate the two lists one at a time to a set of slots (3 slots in my example)

If I pop the first item off each slot, I want that to produce the same order that I round robined them into the slot. So I need padding values.

I want to arrange them into a dictionary of lists that look like this:

```
{0: [[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19]],
1: [[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, -1, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17]],
2: [[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, -1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]]}
```

Notice I have placed a -1 padding value in 1's and 2's keys.

Here's my attempt

```
import math
from pprint import pprint

items = list(range(1, 20))
items2 = list(range(1, 20))
slots = {0: [[]], 1: [[]], 2: [[]]}


def assign_slots(items, slots):
  s = len(slots.keys())
  mina = 0
  wrap = False
  last = 0
  padding = {k: len(v[0]) for k, v in slots.items()}
  print("padding", padding)
  for item in range(0, len(items)):
    wrap = False
    r = math.floor(item / s)
    m = item % s

    if item >= s:
      wrap = True
      mina = len(slots[m][0])
      print(mina)
    if item < s and len(slots[item]) == 0:
      slots[item].append([items[item]])
      
    elif item < s and len(slots[item]) > 0:
      slots[item][0].append(items[item])
     
    elif wrap:
      print("value", items[item], "item is", item, "padding is", padding[m], "length is ", len(slots[m][0]), "r is", r)
   
      # for i in range(item, padding[m] - item):
      #   print("appending empty")
      #   slots[m][0].append(0)
      slots[m][0].append(items[item])
      

    else:

      slots[m][0].append([items[item]])
   
  return slots


results = assign_slots(items, slots)
results2 = assign_slots(items2, slots)

pprint(results2)
running = True
while running:
  has_items = False
  for slot in range(0, len(slots.keys())):
    if len(slots[slot][0]) > 0:
      has_items = True
      item = slots[slot][0]
      if len(item) > 0:
        work = item.pop(0)
        print("doing", work)

      else:
        print("empty")
        slots[slot].pop(0)
  if has_items == False:
    running = False
    break
```

This produces, unfortunately it doesn't match the order that should be the case. It should produce 1-19 twice, in order but it's not in order (the second list goes 2, 3, 1, due to the lack of padding.

```
padding {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}
padding {0: 7, 1: 6, 2: 6}
{0: [[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19]],
 1: [[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17]],
 2: [[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]]}
doing 1
doing 2
doing 3
doing 4
doing 5
doing 6
doing 7
doing 8
doing 9
doing 10
doing 11
doing 12
doing 13
doing 14
doing 15
doing 16
doing 17
doing 18
doing 19
doing 2
doing 3
doing 1
doing 5
doing 6
doing 4
doing 8
doing 9
doing 7
doing 11
doing 12
doing 10
doing 14
doing 15
doing 13
doing 17
doing 18
doing 16
doing 19
```

What's the best way to produce padding and the result I want in an incremental algorithm?

Comment: what is the purpose of nesting a 1d list inside of another list `[[...]]`. Wouldn't one list suffice for this `[ ]`?

Comment: Hi OneMadGypsy, thanks for your reply. my original attempts placed each batch into its own list but i realised i don't need to do that. I think you're right.